# a curvier style of curly brackets

Tags: math-mode, brackets

Older math books often use a curvier, fancier style of curly braces. LaTeX uses [by default] a more conservative, straight kind of curly brackets. Is there a way to get the fancier kind?

[image: An example of curvier, curly braces]

Comment: `Pstricks-add` has  a configurable similar `\psbrace` command, but it is in the context of a pspicture.

Comment: STIX Two Math has a set shaped somewht like this, but much less heavy.